# Search Term not updating from TextField to Firestore StreamBuilder Call

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I am trying to implement a place where users in my app can search my Firestore Database.

[image]

When The user enters a search term into the textField:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TextField(
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
          onSubmitted: (value) {
            setState(() {
              searchKey = value;
              streamQuery = db
                  .collection('GearLockerItems')
                  .where('searchTerm', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchKey)
                  .where('searchTerm', isLessThan: '${searchKey}z')
                  .snapshots();
            });
          },
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Search for Gear',
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

I take the value for the search term and place it into the `streamQuery`

I then take that streamQuery and put it into the StreamBuilder:

```
body: StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
        stream: streamQuery,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          //widget build for complated call
          print('Inside stream $searchKey');

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
```

AS you can see I put a print statement in there for testing and Inside Stream `$searchKey` keeps showing null, which is was I default it to. I do not understand why when I enter data into the search box its not updating the `searchKey` to what ever I type and is keeping it null...

Comment: and what do you see if you `print(value)` before `searchKey = value;`?

Comment: @pskink value before searhKey = value is printing the term I type into the search box

Comment: so you say that after submitting `searchKey` is not null but when `StreamBuilder` callback is called it is null?

Comment: @pskink yea the searchKey in StreamBuilder is stayign default, Its not changing. WHich leads me to believe that streamQuery is not updating with the stream having the updated searchKey value from the text field.

Comment: what exactly do you see if you print searchKey inside both onSubmitted and StreamBuilder callback?

Comment: @pskink I think I may be confusing you becasue I set it as string "null" not actual null: String searchKey = "null";

So that is what is being printed in the print statement for searchKey everywhere in the app. 

If this is being updated:

             streamQuery = db
                  .collection('GearLockerItems')
                  .where('searchTerm', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchKey)
                  .where('searchTerm', isLessThan: '${searchKey}z')
                  .snapshots();
            });

Its not reflecting in the streambuilder or re-running the firestore call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: TextField(
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
      onSubmitted: (value) {
          searchKey = value;
          await db
              .collection('GearLockerItems')
              .where('searchTerm', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchKey)
              .where('searchTerm', isLessThan: '${searchKey}z')
              .snapshots().then((data) { setstate((){streamQuery = data; });});
      },
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Search for Gear',
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: not sure what your answer is saying to do. Could you please add an explanation.

Comment: When you will submit textfield then textfield value will be save into searchKey and wait untill the data is fetch and when data is fetch then function will give you that data and then save your data into your streamQuery and then setState function will work. If you will call setstate before getting data then the data will not show you because it will be available in future.

Answer (score 0):

First fetch the data from firestore and use then function to set state.May it works and don't forget to use await because you wait untill the data is fetched.

Comment: How can I fetch data before knowing what the search term is? The user has to enter it first.